# Is there anyway to resize (Expand both Width and Length) Winform's elements when the window maximized?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have a problem with my GUI, Simply when I maximize the window the design looks and becomes very unbalanced, I have read many articles and documents about TableLayoutPanel, Anchor, and Dock.

[image: Figure 1 - Normal window state]

**Figure 1 - Normal window state**

And when I maximize the window
[image: Figure 2 - Maximized window state]

**Figure 2 - Maximized window state**

And here is what I use in my Winforms GUI:
[image: Figure 3 - Structure]

**Figure 3 - Structure**

Finally, I think if only I could Expand both Width and Length It must look fine(not just anchor), please help me to find a way to make my GUI at least look Balanced.

Comment: It looks like you're happy with the layout in normal state, not happy with the layout when the Form is maximized. But it's not clear what layout in the maximized state would make you happy. Can you post post something that explains it?

Comment: Hello Jimi, Something balanced  it is all I want and happy with.

Comment: Yes, but you need to explain what *balanced* means to you and most of all how this *meaning* applies to a layout. You posted images of what it is, post one that shows what it should be, in your view.